# Missing leading zeros while concatenation

Tags: sql, concatenation

```
SELECT a.amount||' '|| a.ccy AS description1,
       concat(to_char(a.amount, '0.00'),  a.ccy) as description2
FROM products a WHERE a.product_name = 'book';
```

description1 is missing leading zeros. Example:

123.12 USD

.99 USD

description2 is missing blank space and also cannot cast all cases. Example:

#####USD

0.99USD

I want to keep leading zeros and add blank space between amount and currency

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
Select CONCAT (A.Amount,' ',A.CCY)  As Description From Amounts A
WHERE A.Product_Name = 'book';
```